# How to translate a html into different languages in MS CRM 2011?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have created one Html for ms crm 2011, this is in English language.But i want to show the same html in other languages(Arabic,Spanish..etc ) for some users, how i can achieve this,is there any traslating api ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are not translating API. All you can do is to create a separated webresource for every language you want to support and show webresource based on the language of current user.

Answer (score 0):

No OOB functionality exists unfortunately, but it's not as hard as it seems to implement in JS.

All you need is a container with your labels, CRM can tell you the user's language. The script would look like this (taken right out of a working project, which also leverages jQuery ... if you don't, just add it as webresource and include in your HTML page):

```
(function (pageCode, $, undefined) {

    var labels = {
        1033: {
            element1: 'english label for element1',
            element2: 'eng label for element2'
        },
        1040: {
            element1: 'italian label for element1',
            element2: 'italian label for element2'
        },
        xxxx: { 
            element1: 'xxxx language label for element1',
            element2: 'xxxx language label for element2'
        }
    } 
    pageCode.performTranslation = function() {
        var langCode = Xrm.Page.context.getUserLcid();

        if (typeof (locLabels[langCode]) == 'undefined') {
            // You don't have labels for this language... let's go English
            langCode = 1033;
        }

        for (var ctrlName in locLabels[langCode]) {
            $('#' + ctrlName).text(locLabels[langCode][ctrlName]);
        }
    }
}(window.pageCode = window.pageQuote || {}, jQuery));

$(function(){ 
    pageCode.performTranslation(); 
});
```

You'll need to include `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` in your web resource so you have access to `Xrm`, and change what your HTML code looks like in this fashion:

If your HTML is now

```
<label>This is a label</label>
<label>This is another label</label>
```

You should give an `id` to all the translated elements, and the code should become

```
<label id="element1"></label>
<label id="element2"></label>
```

Note that you no longer need to fill the text in the HTML (the JS will take care of it!).